# jQuery onselect datetimepicker change

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Using the datetime picker from http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/, I have to change the max hour when the user clicks a specific date. So far my code makes an AJAX call and gets the max hour on every click of the day(max hour diffrent everyday and lives in databse).

Now I was trying to refresh the view so that the updated maxhour is shown but the form resets to "janaury 0" and when I close the form and click it back the maxhour of the last request if applied to any day selected.

To reset the form i have used options method, that didn't work so i have a method which is called on every `onselect` event that destroys the old property of the datetimepicker and remakes everything and assigns the property.

I even tried using the refresh method of the datetpicker that was supposed to refresh the view.

initial assignment

```
$("#startDate").datetimepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {
        manipulate(date);
    },
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss tt',
    hourMin: 8,
    hourMax: endHour,
    showSecond: false,
    stepMinute: 15,
    minuteGrid: 5,
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: {
        touchonly: false
    },
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "Select a date to check out equipment(s).",
    buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    defaultDate: "+0",
    changeMonth: false,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+5w',
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    ampm: true
});

function manipulate(date) {
    var sendDate = date.toString();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "endtime.php",
        data: {
            day: sendDate
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (XML) {
            var answer = jQuery("data", XML).text();
            var time = answer.split(":");
            var timetemp = sendDate.split(" ");
            var timenew = timetemp[0] + " " + answer;
            //$("#startDate").datetimepicker.( "option" ,hourMax ,time[0]); this is one of the first approach
            $("#startDate").datetimepicker("destroy");
            //$("#startDate").datetimepicker("refresh");
            var DateOptions = {
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    manipulate(date);
                    //$("#startDate").datetimepicker("refresh");
                    //datepicker._gotoToday('#startDate');
                },
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss tt',
                hourMin: 8,
                hourMax: time[0],
                showSecond: false,
                stepMinute: 15,
                minuteGrid: 5,
                addSliderAccess: true,
                sliderAccessArgs: {
                    touchonly: false
                },
                showOn: "button",
                buttonText: "Select a date to check out equipment(s).",
                buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                defaultDate: "+0",
                changeMonth: false,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: '+5w',
                beforeShowDay: unavailable,
                ampm: true,
                setDate: date
            }
            $("#startDate").datetimepicker(DateOptions);
        }
    })
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.